# Laravel: Save css file from database data

Tags: laravel

On the Admin interface I saved the contents of the editor into a database, several css can be created and their order can be changed.

Database table:
id (bigint) | name (varchar) | content (longtext)

This not work:
Storage::disk('local')->append('storage/css/custom.css', $request->input('content'));

When editing, how can I generate the content created in the database and save it to a css file?

update: The backup was resolved but how can I retrieve only the data in the css file from the database is placed before each table: {"content:" ...}?

```
private function saveToFile()
    {
        $cssmerge = Css::all('content');
        Storage::disk('public')->put('css/custom.css', $cssmerge);
}
```

Thanks!

CssController.php:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $csscontent = $request->all();
        // Create css style
        $csscontent = new Css;
        $csscontent->name = $request->input('name');
        $csscontent->content = $request->input('content');
        $csscontent->save();

        return redirect('backend/css')->withSuccessMessage( __('Successfully created!'));
    }

public function update(Request $request, $id)
        {
            // Update css
            Storage::disk('local')->append('storage/css/custom.css', $request->input('content'));
            $csscontent = Css::findOrFail($id);
            $csscontent->name = $request->input('name');
            $csscontent->content = $request->input('content');
            $csscontent->save();

            switch($request->input('save-form')) {
                case 'save-btn-redirect':
                    return redirect('backend/css')->withSuccessMessage( __('Successfully modified!'));
                    break;

                case 'save-btn':
                    return back()->withSuccessMessage( __('Successfully modified!'));
                    break;
            }

            return view('backend.css.index', compact('csscontent'));
        }
```

Comment: post the filesystem.php inside the config directory

Comment: My problem is not accessing the folder, but that custom.css is not saved.

Comment: beause you are saving in the wrong directory, take out the "storage/" inside the append

Comment: Would you write the whole correct line? Either way I try to save it to a file.

Comment: <code>
header{}
header {background:red}
footer{}
a {text-decoration:underline}
header {background:blue}
footer{}
a {text-decoration:underline}
</code>
The route is good, but 'append' always finishes when saving. How do I know that only the items in the current database are included in the file? Prepend, append is not good, and put too, because if I have 3 css tables in the database, I always put the last one saved, the contents of the other two are deleted.

So the contents of the tables must be merged when saving.